# Save every single plot for every column from dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe with 68 columns.

How can I make matplotlib scatter plots with every column and save every single plot?
Now I can only build plots one by one with changing the column's name in X value. (Y value is always the same, it is the target column)

For example, it is the code where I'm changing the X value, but I don't want to change it 68 times and save every plot one by one.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(9,5))
plt.scatter(output_weight['weight_ifas'], output_weight['target_sur'], color='darkred', s = 17)
plt.title('weight_ifas vs target_sur', fontsize=10)
plt.xlabel('weight_ifas', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('target_sur', fontsize=10)
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Is there a good way? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you considered a loop?

Comment: @BigBen I tried but I can't save/download every single plot for every column, it builds a line with all plots in it :(

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] your question with your current loop attempt?

Answer (score 0):

```
for column in output_weight.columns.values.tolist():
   fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,5))
   plt.scatter(output_weight['weight_ifas'], output_weight[column], color='darkred', s = 17)
   plt.title('weight_ifas vs '+column, fontsize=10)
   plt.xlabel('weight_ifas', fontsize=10)
   plt.ylabel(column, fontsize=10)
   plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')
   plt.grid(True)
   plt.show()
   fig.savefig(column+'.png')
```